# Is there a way to see your opponent's rating?

Tags: tower-wars

As far as I can tell, there is no way to determine your oponents' ratings until after the game has finished.  Is there a way to see the ratings before or during the game?  It would be nice to know how badly I should expect to be beaten :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out you can do this by hitting <kbd>f5</kbd> *(there is no way of doing it from the UI)*.